# Getting a line of user input in C help.

Tags: c

I've been all over the web and tried a bunch of different things, but they never seem to work. Every time I run the program it skips over the chance to enter something for the students name and goes straight to the department. Also, we are new to C and were really told to use printf and scanf, but when the user puts in a name like, joe shmo, it does some weird stuff.

```
fputs("Please enter the students name: ", stdout);
fflush(stdout);
fgets(studentArray[empty].name, sizeof studentArray[empty].name, stdin);

printf("\nPlease enter the students department: ");
scanf("%s", studentArray[empty].department);
printf("\nPlease enter the students rank: ");
scanf("%d", &studentArray[empty].rank);
```

EDIT: Weird stuff as in, if I enter two names, ie joe shmo, it will take joe as the name and automatically add shmo to the department. studentArray is an array of a struct I made...

```
typedef struct {
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
char department[MAX_DEPT_LENGTH];
int rank;
} student;
```

Comment: Please define "weird stuff".  Also, please provide the definition of `studentArray`.

Comment: Is there any code before this that you are not showing?

Comment: Try to not mix `scanf()` and `fgets()` -- prefer `fgets()` followed by parsing the input.

Answer (score 4):

When the program reaches the `fgets()` I bet there is a pending `'\n'` in the input buffer from a previous `scanf()`. I suggest you get rid of that `'\n'` and any previous input.

For example, with

```
int getridofextrainput(void) {
  int ch;
  while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) /* void */;
  return ch;
}
```

Then use that function in your code where you think it's necessary (before `fgets`).

Comment: Might want to add `ungetc` to that function

Comment: @anatolyg: why? ???!?! Basically I want to get rid of the last `'\n'` in the buffer, which is the last character read. Why would I put the character I don't want back?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you mix `fscanf` and `fgets`.

When `fscanf` reads a number, it stops right at the end of this number, *before* the following newline character. When afterwards `fgets` reads a string, it stops at the next newline character, which unfortunately immediately follows.

If you used only `fscanf` to read all data, you would not get problems. This is not trivial, because some of your names contain spaces. It is possible to read a name containing a space using `fscanf` like this:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", studentArray[empty].department);
```

If you used only `fgets` to read all data, you would be OK either. Unfortunately, this is not trivial too: it requires a temporary buffer for reading numbers.

```
char temp[42];
fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin);
sscanf(temp, "%d", &studentArray[empty].rank);
```